# store array in html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/4px4whk0/
I have two question

1. when first click the `checkbox` (a), the first `console.log` should be print the dom with empty `data-selected-list` attribute, I don't know why it filled what I click already (["a"]) ?
   I have to set timeout wrap the `container.attr('data-selected-list', selectedList);` then it works like what I want.
2. when click other `checkbox` (b), I hope it will be `["a","b"]` store in attribute. but it only store `["b"]` , why?

I hope it can be solve by store data in html attribute not only store in jquery `data` api

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.container').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var container = $(this).closest('.container');
        var input = $(this);
        console.log(container);
        
        var selectedList = container.data('selected-list');
        if (selectedList == '') {
          selectedList = [];
        }
        
        
        if (input.is(":checked")) {
          selectedList.push(input.val());
        }
        
        console.log(selectedList);
        selectedList = JSON.stringify(selectedList);
        
        container.attr('data-selected-list', selectedList);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-selected-list="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a">a
    <input type="checkbox" value="b">b
    <input type="checkbox" value="c">c
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several mistakes:

1. if you want to print the results of your array *before* you change it, then move the `console.log` call to *before* you push to the array
2. you were using `attr` and `data` interchangeably. These do two different things. `attr` stores the data in the DOM and `data` is a jquery method that stores the data somewhere within jquery itself.
3. finally, if you're using `attr` you need to do `JSON.stringify` to serialize your array before storing it (which you did do correctly) but when you pull the data out of the DOM you have to convert it back to an array with `JSON.parse`
4. jquery's `attr` returns `undefined` for an undefined DOM tag, not empty string

the right solution with these problems fixed is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $('.container');
    container.on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var input = $(this);
        console.log(container);

        var selectedList = container.attr('data-selected-list');
        if (!selectedList) {
          selectedList = [];
        }else{
          selectedList = JSON.parse(selectedList);
        }


        console.log(selectedList);
        if (input.is(":checked")) {
          selectedList.push(input.val());
        }

        selectedList = JSON.stringify(selectedList);

        container.attr('data-selected-list', selectedList);
    });

});
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLz6uv1q/

Comment: *"then move the console.log call to before you push to the array"* Not necessarily. Consoles are known for giving a live preview of objects. It all depends on the console and version.

Comment: Another note is perhaps drop `input.is(":checked")` in favour of `input.checked` to save an unneeded call to jQuery

Comment: @BenedictLewis: `input` is a jQuery object already. It would have to be `this.checked` and `this.value` for that to work.

Comment: @Macmee: Also, there's no `selected-list` attribute, so your `.attr()` call will fail.

Comment: @squint not true - `container.attr('selected-list')` will return undefined, which causes `selectedList` to be set to an empty array - same as in your answer (infact the code for this is what I wrote myself so you either c&p'd that from my answer or somehow ended up in my jsfiddle fork :P )

Comment: @Macmee: I posted my answer *before* yours, so how could I copy it? But my point is that you will ***always*** get `undefined` because there is no `selected-list` attribute.

Comment: @squint you edited your post with my code after I posted my answer, I can see it in your posts edit history here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33860494/revisions - I'm assuming you ended up on my fiddle and not his and that it wasnt blatant answer copying :)

but anywho, `selected-list` gets set so its not true that it's undefined every time - only the first time. Look at the 4th last line: `container.attr('selected-list', selectedList);`

Comment: @squint and whats up with the downvote? My answer works (check my fiddle) and you're the one that copied me. Dude, it's not all about scoring points, what are you doing?!

Comment: @Macmee: My live demo was there before your jsFiddle. I did change the `== ""` code later for better form, however it's not required because the HTML has `data-selected-list=""`, so you're wrong about needing to handle `undefined` as well. So the trouble with yours is that if the server sends some data, you'll be ignoring it. Also, you're changing the attribute used, which could affect other parts of the application.

Comment: ...and it's obviously not about scoring points for me since mine is a community wiki, yet somehow it got downvoted even though it was correct from the start. Hmmm...

Comment: @squint if you're insinuating that I downvoted you, and you did infact downvote my answer then that means you downvoted me because you thought I downvoted you. And I still think it's awfully convenient how after I answered the question you edited your answer and ended up with something *remarkably similar* to my answer, but hey, it's not all about the points :)

Comment: Nope, I told you exactly why I downvoted you. Your answer was wrong. Believe me, If I had copied you, I would have been copying very obviously flawed code. Glad to see you finally fixed it. You're coming along just fine. :)

Comment: @squint my answer's not wrong, go here http://jsfiddle.net/sLgtpa6b/ and check the boxes. Observe how the output is identical to what OP wanted. You edited your originally wrong answer to contain the correct answer *I* wrote up, and then you downvoted me so that your answer would appear above mine. And then you commented on my answer saying it was incorrect when it works fine (again, see the fiddle).

Comment: @Macmee: Ah, you're trying to rewrite history. Why are you so upset? Again, look at my revision history. It was correct from the start, whereas you just edited yours to fix it. Don't take it so personally. There's really nothing to get that upset about. I'm sure you're a fine developer.

Comment: @squint I am looking at your post history and I see an edit right *after* I posted my answer which contains my code lol

Comment: thanks for reply, in my question 1 is I want to know how to print container before store

Comment: @Macmee: If it contained your code, it would be accessing the wrong attribute. Like I said, you're probably plenty competent. Don't let it upset you so much.